# add a command in the beginning of quotation mark by using bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl, sed

I would like to use sed to do the following steps:

```
before: test="testabc"

after: test="quiz testabc"
```

How can I add quiz followed by a space in the beginning of the quotation mark?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: `sed 's/="/&quiz /g'` should do

Comment: even learning simple sed syntax of `s/search/replace/` would have given you `sed 's/"/"quiz /'` ... honest question, is it really that difficult to search for sed examples? and you could always check info pages here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the following `sed` command

```
$ echo 'test="testabc"' | sed 's/="\([^"]*\)"/="quiz \1"/'                                                                                     
test="quiz testabc"
```

Explanations:

- `s/pattern/replacement/` use sed in search/replace mode.
- `="\([^"]*\)"` this regex will fetch `="some string"`.
- then you can use a capturing group `( )` and back reference `\1` to it in order to keep the string content and add your quiz
- `s/pattern/replacement/g` use the global replacement mode if you need to search and replace more than one occurrence of this pattern

or the following `perl` solution works as well:

```
$ echo 'test="testabc"' | perl -pe 's/(?<==")([^"]*)(?=")/quiz \1/'
test="quiz testabc"
```

For regex details: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

**Improvements:**

- `sed 's/test="\([^"]*\)"/test="quiz \1"/'` add the variable name to be sure to change only that variable.
- `sed 's/="/&quiz /g'` or if you don't care about the variable names and want to change every assignation.